# AWS code comitter EncryptionKeyAccessDeniedException errors after IP restriction policy. How to fix?

Tags: amazon-web-services

when i load CodeComitter main page i have an empty error and i traced `EncryptionKeyAccessDeniedException` error. When i open my repo, i have `Access is denied because a problem occurred with the encryption key`.

here is my IAM policy (where i limit access only for 2 IPs).
With this policy (ip limit part)  i can use GIT tool via SSH but cant use AWS console.
Without ip limitint part i can use aws console AND git tool too.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "ipv4_here",
                        "ipv4_again_here"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:BatchGet*",
                "codecommit:Get*",
                "codecommit:List*",
                "codecommit:Create*",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
                "codecommit:Describe*",
                "codecommit:Put*",
                "codecommit:Post*",
                "codecommit:Merge*",
                "codecommit:Test*",
                "codecommit:Update*",
                "codecommit:GitPull",
                "codecommit:GitPush"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "CloudWatchEventsCodeCommitRulesAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:DeleteRule",
                "events:DescribeRule",
                "events:DisableRule",
                "events:EnableRule",
                "events:PutRule",
                "events:PutTargets",
                "events:RemoveTargets",
                "events:ListTargetsByRule"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:events:*:*:rule/codecommit*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SNSTopicAndSubscriptionAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:codecommit*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMReadOnlyConsoleAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:ListServiceSpecificCredentials",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMUserSSHKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeleteSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:GetSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:ListSSHPublicKeys",
                "iam:UpdateSSHPublicKey",
                "iam:UploadSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "IAMSelfManageServiceSpecificCredentials",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:UpdateServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:DeleteServiceSpecificCredential",
                "iam:ResetServiceSpecificCredential"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find a way how to restrist access to 2 ips AND keep aws console working for them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is our network restrictions managed policy cloudformation resource with a comment explaining why it addresses your issue:

```
networkRestrictions:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        # NOTE: Code Commit accesses KMS as your user using a fake ip
        # address of `codecommit.amazonaws.com`. This value isn't a valid
        # so IAM policy validation won't allow it in the SourceIp conditions
        # It also provides no other fields that we can match on to limit
        # KMS operations to the codecommit service.
        #
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/encryption.html
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873309/aws-code-comitter-encryptionkeyaccessdeniedexception-errors-after-ip-restriction#
        #
        - Effect: Deny
          NotAction:
            - kms:Decrypt
            - kms:Encrypt
            - kms:Decrypt
            - kms:ReEncrypt
            - kms:GenerateDataKey
            - kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext
            - kms:DescribeKey
          Resource: "*"
          Condition:
            NotIpAddress:
              aws:SourceIp:
                - "10.1.2.0/24"
```

Comment: i will try it in next days and post a reply. Thanks!